# Display Total of Dynamically created rows and columns in Gridview of ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I'am using Gridview in my ASP.net application. This Gridview is used to display figures, the rows as well as columns in the gridview are generated dynamically i.e the number of rows and columns are not fixed. I want to display total of all the rows in particular footer row and also total of columns, As shown below [image]

I want to Display total as displayed in Bold in datagridview. Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for the sum of every column you can use the RowDataBound

you need to have a global variable that you can add the column of every row to it.
and show it in the footer.

```
decimal _totalUnitPrice = 0m;

protected void ProductsInCategory_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {

     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
          (myObject) product = (myObject)((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
             _totalUnitPrice += product.UnitPrice;
      }
}
```

and then show the footer

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer){
   e.Row.Cells[1].Text = _totalUnitPrice.ToString("c");
}
```

you will need to have a list on global items so you can have multiple sums for every column

Comment: But the rows are also generated dynamically.

Comment: yes, but you still get the data from dataset. so you bind the gridview to a data container.